# Hong Kong ID chip command and response APDU

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I have written a program to communicate with a smart card that will get the data from the new Hong Kong ID. I could successfully connect to card. Does anyone have an idea what command and response APDU I can use to retrieve the data?

I have searched the web to get any idea, but I didn't get any.
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: It appears, that the ID card was provided by an international group (may be Thales / Gemalto). In that case chances are good, that the specification also follows an international specification. For travel documents the gold standard is the ICAO specification. Whether that forms the basis for the Hongkong card can probably better be answered by someone, capable of reading Mandarin as well.

Comment: Thanks @guidot. I think they still return english response the same with Malaysia ID. I was able to get the data from Malaysia ID provided the command APDU. But for Hong Kong I can't since I can't find any reference for the commands. All I can get from the card is 6891 responses.